# Apple Thunderbolt Display Causing Big Performance Problems with M1 Max MBP

Tags: display, usb, apple-silicon, thunderbolt-display

I've got an OG Apple Thunderbolt Display that I'm connecting to a M1 Max MacBook Pro using the Apple Thunderbolt 2 to 3 adapter. It works for the most part, but I'm getting pretty drastic performance problems—display/mouse stutter, apps not responding or taking unusually log to display their contents, failure to keep up with keyboard input—that appear when I plug the display in and disappear when I unplug it.

I can say that using a Thunderbolt 2 dock in the middle exhibits the same behavior and I don't see anything surprising in Activity Monitor.

Any ideas or solutions to this problem anyone can suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you experience the problem when the TB display is directly connected to the Mac with the dock completely disconnected?

Comment: Also, I presume you mean 3 to 2 adaptor? [Peripheral connections go **from** computer **to** device.]

Comment: @Allan Yes, the dock has been removed entirely. I thought for sure that would fix the problem, but no dice.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, this guy. https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter

Comment: Have you checked for anything in Activity Monitor? Memory or CPU% issues? I've seen anecdotally that the M-series are great… until they come under pressure, then they're very poor.

Comment: I’ve seen wireless mouse stutter with poorly shielded Thunderbolt cables but nothing like that would affect system performance.  Try booting into Safe mode to rule out 3rd party software

Comment: I'd do all the usual troubleshooting steps: test Safe Boot mode; test a brand new user account. If you have a spare TB2 cable, try connecting the Mac to the TB port, to rule out problems with the built-in cable (which are well-known).

Comment: I'm not sure what the appropriate way to handle this is for StackExchange, but the problem just went away.  FWIW, I did try many of the troubleshooting steps mentioned above and appreciate the suggestions. It feels like connecting the monitor or adapter kicked off some heavy background configuration process that went on for hours but finally completed, though I can't imagine what that would be. Thanks everyone.